# Can I get my old questions assigned to me after I register?

Tags: support, specific-question, sign-up

Would it be possible to assign a question I asked yesterday to my newly created account? I registered via OpenID this morning. It's just about the reputation ;-)

This is regarding [routing problem under Mac OS X](https://serverfault.com/questions/200506/routing-problem-under-mac-os-x) on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember right, yes, this is possible. All you have to do is flag the question for Moderator Attention and state that you'd like it to be merged into your account.

Of course, you should only do that with your own questions.