# I have many points but I'm not registered

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)
>   [how to register my unregistered account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42267/how-to-register-my-unregistered-account)

Hi

I have an account in StackOverflow for quite some time but I never took the time to register.

I want to have that same account and username but I want to be a registered user so I can favorite questions.

How can I do that without losing the points and questions I have?

Comment: Since you need a registered account in order to post on Meta Stack Overflow, I'm assuming you had to register a separate account instead of registering your original account. In that case, please [follow these instructions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste): flag a post of yours for moderator attention and request a user account merge. Specify the profile page for your other account, and provide any other identifying info if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by questions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42267/how-to-register-my-unregistered-account) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69960/can-i-get-my-old-questions-assigned-to-me-after-i-register), you can simply use the "register" link at the top of the page to make a registered account, and if you find your registered account to be lacking questions, you can ask a moderator to merge them in.

(This is, of course, all assuming you currently do not have a registered account.)